# How to change recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, recursion

How do I change the function so that it ceases to be recursive? I think the memory buffer is being filled.

**code:**

```
def start_play():
    start = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[27]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span')
    start = start.text
    start = re.findall(r'\d+', start)

    if len(start) == 0:
        # t.sleep(2)
        return start_play()
    else:
        if start[0] == '3' or start[0] == '4':
            comparison()
        else:
            return start_play()
        
def check_win_or_lose():
    start = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[27]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span')
    start = start.text
    start = re.findall(r'\d+', start)

    if len(start) == 0:
        return check_win_or_lose()
    else:
        if start[0] == '22' or start[0] == '23':
            check()
            last_bet.clear()
        else:
            return check_win_or_lose()
```

Comment: There's no exit condition in your code. It runs until max depth is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is your two functions in iterative way :

```py
def start_play():
    while True:
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[27]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span')
        start = re.findall(r'\d+', span.text)
        if start and start[0] in ('3', '4'):
            comparaison()
            break


def check_win_or_lose():
    while True:
        span = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[27]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span')
        start = re.findall(r'\d+', span.text)
        if start and start[0] in ('22', '23'):
            check()
            last_bet.clear()
            break
```

Comment: `if len(start) != 0` can be reduced to just `if start`

Comment: Actually it can be further simplified to `start[0] in ('3', '4')` and similarly for the second case.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard at all. Just don't have the function call itself. If you want it to loop forever, say so explicitly.

```py
def wrong():
   # do things here
   return wrong()

def right():
    while True:
        # do things here
```

If you want to exit the `while True:` somewhere in `# do things here`, you can do that with `break`.

```py
def wrong_too():
   # do things here
   if something:
       # do nothing, or something else
   else:
       return wrong_too()

def right_too():
    while True:
        # do things here
        if something:
            break
```

In more complex cases, maybe use a state variable.

```py
def right_also():
    done = False
    while not done:
        # do things here
        while complex_stuff():
            for loop in values():
                if something_particular():
                    # We want to escape down at the end of the while True
                    done = True
```